# Understanding `conduit` Output

Tags: haskell

Using Conduit, given:

```
Prelude> :t (yieldMany [1..10] .| mapC show .| mapC print .| sinkList)
(yieldMany [1..10] .| mapC show .| mapC print .| sinkList)
  :: Monad m => ConduitM a c m [IO ()]
```

Why doesn't any output get logged?

```
Prelude> runConduit $ yieldMany [1..10] .| mapC show .| mapC print .| sinkList
Prelude>
```

My expectation was that, for a stream of `[1..10]`, each element's `String`, i.e. `show`, value would be printed.

Please explain this output.

Comment: IIRC, you had a similar problem in your recent CR question. Please use proper source files with type annotations when you encounter problems like this. You will often notice that GHCi works a little bit different when you use `IO`. If you add type annotations, GHC will yell at you that the result of `runConduit $ …` is _not_ a `IO [()]`, but a `IO [IO ()]`.

Answer (score 6):

The result of the conduit is a list of `IO ()` in a monad, not a single `IO ()`:

```
Prelude Conduit> :t runConduit $ yieldMany [1..10] .| mapC show .| mapC print .| sinkList
runConduit $ yieldMany [1..10] .| mapC show .| mapC print .| sinkList
  :: Monad m => m [IO ()]
```

Even if you set `m` to `IO`, you end up with `IO [IO ()]` as result, which doesn't get shown because `[IO ()]` does not have a `Show` instance. You can fix that if you add `>>= sequence_`:

```
(runConduit $ yieldMany [1..10] .| mapC show .| mapC print .| sinkList) >>= sequence_
```

However, the real problem is that you use `mapC print` instead of `mapMC print`:

```
Prelude Conduit> :t mapC
mapC :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> Conduit a m b
Prelude Conduit> :t mapMC
mapMC :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> Conduit a m b
```

If you use `mapC print`, you end up with `Conduit a m (IO ())`. If you use `mapMC print`, you end up with `Conduit a IO ()`. The latter sets `m` to `IO`, the first does not.

So use the correct combinator for monadic functions:

```
runConduit $ yieldMany [1..10] .| mapC show .| mapMC print .| sinkNull
--                                                ^
```

Also, check the type of `it` in GHCi if you don't get the expected result.